# wordwrap not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull a string out of my mysql DB and use a working to add `<br />` tags to it. But it's not working and I cant work out why

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res)){
    echo '<div id="contents">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $UserName = $row['UserName'];
    $Message = $row['Message'];

    $MessageW = wordwrap($Message, 10, "<br />\n");

      echo '<div><strong>' .
            $UserName . ': </strong>' .
            $MessageW . '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: "It is not working" is *never* a good error description. What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: There is not enough information here for anyone to help you. At the very least you need to explain in detail what part isn't working and you probably need to include the part with the query.

Comment: it was doing nothing the string was just coming out the same with or without the wordwrap there.

Comment: "Its not Working" i'm agree that is not a good error description, but, is perfect for google search..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's unlikely that all words in your message have a length of 10 characters. By default, PHP does not cut in words, so pass a fourth parameter of `true` to force cutting in the middle of words.

Also, your code is vulnerable to XSS. To solve this, first `wordwrap` it, then convert the result to HTML and finally convert newlines:

```
$MessageW = wordwrap($Message, 10, "\n", true);
$MessageW = htmlentities($MessageW);
$MessageW = nl2br($MessageW);
```

Comment: is there a way i can ask it to cut in before the last word so it dose not cut the word up

Comment: @1ftw1 It does, but lines bigger than 10 characters will not fit then and you would come back to SO with a new question "why does my wordwrap not work?" =/

Comment: Thank Lekensteyn you have been a big help. Is XSS a big deal here seeing im just reading it from the DB?

Comment: If it's retrieved from the database (persistent storage) and users are allowed to insert random data, you're prone to "persistent XSS". XSS is an issue when outputting unsanitized data, it doesn't matter if it comes from the database, a file or user input ($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, ...)

Comment: Thank Lekensteyn i will look in to that ta :)

Comment: I was pissed off because my app written in PHP suddenly stoped outputting wrapped, even there is no wrap at the end of a word, but your solution really helped me. 
Thanks.

I still wondering how to wrap exactly at the end of the world, because it doesn't work like it should.